# Grid search parameter combinations in Python

Tags: python, combinatorics

For a computation engineering model, I want to do a grid search for all feasible parameter combinations. Each parameter has a certain possibility range, e.g. (0 … 100) and the parameter combination must fulfil the condition `a+b+c=100`. An example:

```
ranges = {
    'a': (95, 99), 
    'b': (1, 4), 
    'c': (1, 2)}
increment = 1.0
target = 100.0
```

So the combinations *that fulfil the condition* `a+b+c=100` are:

```
[(95, 4, 1), (95, 3, 2), (96, 2, 2), 
 (96, 3, 1), (97, 1, 2), (97, 2, 1), 
 (98, 1, 1)]
```

This algorithm should run with any number of parameters, range lengths, and increments.

The solutions I have come up with is brute-forcing the problem. That means calculating *all* combinations and then discarding the ones that do not fulfil the given condition. I have to use `np.isclose()`, because when using floats, the rounding error in Python's will not lead to an exact sum.

```
def solution(ranges, increment, target):
    combinations = []
    for parameter in ranges:
        combinations.append(list(np.arange(ranges[parameter][0], ranges[parameter][1], increment)))
        # np.arange() is exclusive of the upper bound, let's fix that
        if combinations[-1][-1] != ranges[parameter][1]:
            combinations[-1].append(ranges[parameter][1])
    result = []
    for combination in itertools.product(*combinations):
        # using np.isclose() so that the algorithm works for floats
        if np.isclose(sum(combination), target):
            result.append(combination)
    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=ranges.keys())
    return df
```

However, this quickly takes a few days to compute. Hence, both solutions are not viable for large number of parameters and ranges. For instance, one set that I am trying to solve is (already unpacked `combinations` variable):

```
[[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0], 
 [22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0, 33.0, 34.0, 35.0, 36.0, 37.0, 38.0, 39.0, 40.0, 41.0, 42.0, 43.0, 44.0, 45.0, 46.0, 47.0, 48.0, 49.0, 50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 55.0, 56.0, 57.0, 58.0, 59.0, 60.0, 61.0, 62.0, 63.0, 64.0, 65.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0, 69.0, 70.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0, 79.0, 80.0, 81.0, 82.0, 83.0, 84.0, 85.0, 86.0, 87.0, 88.0], 
 [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0],
 [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0], [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0], 
 [0.0, 1.0, 2.0],
 [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0], 
 [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], 
 [0.0], 
 [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 30.0, 31.0, 32.0], 
 [0.0]]
```

This results in memory use of >40 GB and calculation time >400 hours.
Do you see a solution that is either faster or more intelligent, i.e. not trying to brute-force the problem?

Comment: Maybe a bit trivial, but just found that doing a first check with `sum()` *before* doing the actual check with `np.isclose()` saves a lot of time.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.StackExchange! Do you know what the condition is going to be like ? In your case, it seems to be linear constraint. Will it always be the case ?

Comment: Sorry - not sure if I understand the question. The condition is that the sum of the combinations must equal the `target` variable, which is constant.

Comment: Ha ok, fair enough, I didn't understand that the condition was always that the sum of the params should be equal to the target value.

Comment: Also, are the values known to be all positive ?

Comment: Yes. Zeros are allowed. Should work for floats though.

Comment: Looks suspiciously similar to a [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem. Don't hold your breath.

Comment: Since you've only implied this: are (a, b, c) required to be integers, or can they take floating-point values between whole numbers?

Comment: If, within your generated valid combinations, some have more merit than others, this is an ideal problem for ILP. Is that the case?

Comment: @Reinderien It should work with floats, yes. Not sure if I get the point about ILP. The numbers will be inputs to a non-linear model to find ideal parameter combinations.

Comment: @n1000 Can you provide information on what the non-linear model is? It would be more efficient to combine that with the work of this current program.

Answer (score 2):

## split

The method does a few things at the same time.

- It expands the ranges
- generates the combinations
- takes the sums
- compares to the target
- assembles a DataFrame

better would be to split it up in a few logical units. This will not only help freeing memory in-between steps, but also help with debugging the intermediate values

## looping

Check the talk "Looping like a pro"

You loop over the index, and end up with real long variables like `ranges[parameter][0]`. If you use tuple expansion, you can do this:

```
def expand(ranges, increment):
    for start, end in ranges.values():
        expansion= list(np.arange(start, end, increment))
        # np.arange() is exclusive of the upper bound, let's fix that
        if expansion[-1] != end:
            expansion.append(end)
        yield expansion
```

For me, this is a lot clearer. It also has the benefit of keeping the lines shorter.

Since it are more the expansions of the ranges you create instead of the combinations, I renamed the method and variables.

This also uses a generator instead of an intermediate list.

This alternative might even simpler:

```
def expand(ranges, increment):
    for start, end in ranges.values():
        yield  np.arange(start, end + increment/2, increment)
```

This can then be combined and summed like this:

```
def combine_naive(expansions, target):
    for combination in itertools.product(*expansions):
        # using np.isclose() so that the algorithm works for floats
        if np.isclose(sum(combination), target):
            yield combination
```

I like your comment there. It explains why you use `np.isclose` instead of `==`

## Alternative approaches

### numpy

instead of having `itertools.product` assemble the combinations, you could use `numpy.meshgrid`

```
def combine_numpy(expansions, target):
    grid = np.meshgrid(*expansions)
    summary = np.array(grid).sum(axis=0)
    indices = np.where(np.isclose(summary, target))
    return (
        [row[i] for row, i in zip(expansions, idx)]
        for idx in zip(*indices)
    )
```

This is approximately the same, but staying in the `numpy` universe. You can reduce the memory footprint here with the correct choice of `dtype` and reducing the number of intermediary variables

## sorted

or you could use the fact the expansions are sorted, and break when a sum is over the target. This uses recursion, tuple unpacking and the fact an empty sequence is `False`y.

```
def combine_sorted(expansions, target, previous=()):
    series, *rest = expansions

    sum_max = sum(item[-1] for item in rest)
    for item in series:
        current = previous + (item,)
        sum_current = sum(current)
        if rest:
            if sum_current + sum_max < target and not np.isclose(
                sum_current + sum_max, target
            ):
                continue
            yield from combine_sorted(rest, target, previous=current)
        else:
            if np.isclose(sum_current, target):
                yield current
            elif sum_current > target:
                return
```

The `sum_max` is to skip numbers where the total some will be less than `target` as soon as possible.

testing and timing with real data will show which option is more memory and CPU intensive.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ranges = {"a": (95, 99), "b": (1, 4), "c": (1, 2)}
    increment = 1.0
    target = 100.0
    df = solution(ranges, increment, target)

    expansions = list(expand(ranges, increment))
    results = list(combine_naive(expansions, target))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=ranges.keys())
    print(df1)

    results_sorted = list(combine_sorted(expansions, target))
    print(results_sorted)
    df_sorted = pd.DataFrame(results_sorted, columns=ranges.keys())
    print(df_sorted)

    results_numpy = list(combine_numpy(expansions, target))
    print(results_numpy)
    df_sorted = pd.DataFrame(results_numpy, columns=ranges.keys())
    print(df_sorted)
```

Comment: Actually my first try was to put all combinations into a dataframe and drop all that were not equal to the target. But I ran into memory issues. Your solutions and feedback are nice! Here are calculation time and max. memory usage for a relatively large example: `combine_naive()`: 32.3min, 60.3MB, `combine_sorted()`: 6.1min, 60.5MB, `combine_numpy()`: 0.4min, 6761MB. Seems like `combine_sorted()` may be a great compromise between speed and memory.

Comment: you can do both. Try the `combine_numpy` and catch the `MemoryError`. If it doesn't succeed, fall back to the `combine_sorted`

Comment: Hmm. Intereseting. I did not get a `MemoryError`, however. MacOS started swapping like crazy. I am not sure if it is easily possible to keep taps on the memory consumption of a script. @Maarten Fabré

Comment: another possibility would be to calculate the number of combinations (product of the lengths of the ranges), and decide based on that

Answer (score 1):

This is (nearly) the perfect application for [ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), with a catch - whereas you want to enumerate *all* possible combinations, ILP is for convex optimization within certain constraints, has a cost metric, and only outputs *the best* possible combination (where you define best).

You haven't given us a lot of detail on the "computation engineering model", but it's likely that not all of your output combinations are preferable, and there's some other selection process at work after your Python program has run. *If* you can capture this selection process as a linear cost metric, then ILP was made for your problem.

If you're married to Python, then you can use Numpy and the [`scipy.optimize.linprog`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) package, but it has some shortcomings - prominently, that it doesn't support ILP, only LP (with floating-point values). If you aren't married to Python, then use something like [`glpk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) - either directly or through something like [Octave's interface](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/Linear-Programming.html).

To illustrate, following along with Chapter 1.1 of the [glpk documentation](https://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~elias/glpk.pdf) and matching it to your example:

- Your a, b, and c would form a three-element vector *x* that glpk is responsible for determining
- You would have to create a matrix *c* to determine the cost ("objective") function against which glpk will optimize
- Your `ranges` would be converted into the vectors *l* and *u*
- The constraint coefficient matrix *a* would be set to a vector of all 1s
- Your `target` would be converted into the "constraint auxiliary variable"

If you actually need to constrain the output to whole numbers (i.e. your `increment` is 1), then use MIP ("mixed integer linear programming") mode directly.

If `increment` is not 1 and you still need to constrain output to a linear space following those increments, you'll need a pre- and post-scaling operation so that you're still using MIP.

If it actually doesn't matter that the numbers be constrained to increments at all, then just use LP mode.